# preferred://browser?

Tags: launcher

I have recently installed Ubuntu Studio, and installed all the packages offered by the app:

```
sudo ubuntustudio-installer
```

In the task bar, just to the right of Application Launcher's icon there is a gray rectangular icon with the "?" character in it. I created a desktop link from this, and opened this with KWrite. This is what I saw:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Icon=unknown
Name=preferred://browser
Type=Link
URL[$e]=preferred://browser
```

What is the intent of this icon?

The OS is Ubuntu 22.04 with encrypted ZFS, and RAID. No install script was used. It is a custom installation. The procedure I used to do the installation I document in this LibreOffice file:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/2w8mdb96tbzslub/Ubuntu_22.04_Root_on_ZFS_Encryption.odt/file

Comment: You haven't provided any OS/release details; but the usual icon may not exist on your existing install; so the *unknown* causes a valid (unknown catch all) to be used I believe  (*release details of your system may allow more precise details to be provided as the installation scripts can vary slightly for different releases & you gave no details on which you are asking about*)

Comment: I added the information you requested/